# Only frame with rounded corners and shadow using attach boxed in `tcolorbox`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, colorbox

I'm trying to get a box style (more or less) like this:

[image: Espected]

But with the `rounded edges` and `shadow` (that image is my best effort with Gimp ...)

I've been trying to adapt an example of the `tcolorbox` documentation. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Example 123,drop fuzzy shadow= lightgray,%
colframe=gray,colback=white,colbacktitle=white,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,boxrule=0.2mm,%
coltitle=black,attach boxed title to top right=
{yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},%
boxed title style={boxrule=0.2mm,drop fuzzy shadow= lightgray,%
frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-0mm]frame.west)
-- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=-2mm]frame.east)
-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
-- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
-- ([xshift=0mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
-- cycle;} }]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

And that's what the output looks like:
[image: Current]

It looks something (well, but, well away) like what I'm looking for. How do I get this box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be the simplest to just draw everything with the `frame code`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Example 123,drop fuzzy shadow= lightgray,%
colframe=gray,colback=white,colbacktitle=white,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,
boxrule=0mm,%
coltitle=black,
attach boxed title to top right=
{yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},%
boxed title style={empty,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt},
frame code={
\draw[rounded corners=2pt,line width=0.4pt]  let \p1=($(title.north)-(frame.north)$) in
(title.north) --  (title.north west) -- ++ (-\y1+0.2pt,-\y1+0.2pt) -|
([xshift=-0.2pt,yshift=-0.2pt]frame.south west) -| ([xshift=0.2pt]frame.east)   |- ([xshift=1em]title.north) [rounded corners=0pt] -- cycle ;}]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are the one, every time I see one of your answers you make things look very simple...Thanks again